# Complexity of a tree labeling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, complexity-theory

I have a generic weighted tree (undirected graph without cycles, connected) with n nodes and n-1 edges connecting a node to another one.

My algorithm does the following:

> do
>
> - compute the actual leaves (nodes with degree 1)
> - remove all the leaves and their edges from the tree labelling each parent with the maximum value of the cost of his connected leaves
>     (for example if an internal node is connected to two leaf with edges with costs 5,6 then we label the internal node after removing the leaves with 6)
>
> until the tree has size <= 2
>
> return the node with maximum cost labelled

Can I say that the complexity is `O(n)` to compute the leaves and `O(n)` to eliminate each edge with leaf, so I have `O(n)+O(n) = O(n)`?

Comment: You estimated the complexity of a single step of this algorithm, not the whole algorithm. Since you need to repeat this operation `O(depth)` times, you need to take these repetitions into account.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this in O(n) with a set implemented as a simple list, queue, or stack (order of processing is unimportant).

Put all the leaves in the set.

In a loop, remove a leaf from the set, delete it and its edge from the graph.  Process the label by updating the max of the parent.  If the parent is now a leaf, add it to the set and keep going.

When the set is empty you're done, and the node labels are correct.

Initially constructing the set is O(n).  Every vertex is placed on the set, removed and its label processed exactly once. That's all constant time.  So for n nodes it is O(n) time.  So we have O(n) + O(n) = O(n).

Comment: you would need a queue in particular for this one. Parent cannot be removed before child nodes as then the max is not correct so stack and simple list wouldnt work.

Comment: @VikramBhat  Order doesn't matter.  You never have anything but leaves in the set.

Comment: I think there is no other way to do it other than my implementation below and using queue with leaves entering first like in your case is analogous to leaves entering last in stack implementation as i have done check my algorithm of it. You should use stack or queue in similar fashion to solve the problem

Comment: You should specify use of queue in above case or tell how u check that the parent is leaf.

Comment: @VikramBhat The only nodes that ever go in the set are leaves.  A leaf cannot be the parent of any other node.  Therefore you're never removing a parent before its children.

Comment: Yes u r right that parent can be added if all its child nodes are processed but how do you check whether they are processed.

Comment: I mean do you use a counter or flag or something like that for every node because u would need it if u r not using a queue

Comment: @VikramBhat As my post says, when you process a leaf, you remove it (along with its edge) from the graph.  If the parent is now a leaf (a node with only one edge left), then add it to the set.  Checking whether there is only one edge incident on a node is a constant time operation with any reasonable data structure.

Comment: Okay so you are assuming that child has a pointer of parent then it is fine. I was assuming that the parent has child pointers and not the visa versa so i implemented the recursive version

Comment: thanks everybody.. i think the solution of Gene is very good because for my purpose i can first explore all the tree, once i found all the leafs i put them in a queue and process them.. every leaf has an edge to the parent with associated cost so i can update the cost on the parent and at the same time verify if this parent has remaining degree equal to 1..

Comment: sorry i have not specified in an undirected tree, i have two-way edges (references)

Comment: @user2995453 you created confusion between Gene and me because of that

Comment: @Gene sorry for confusion

Comment: i'm sorry for that.. so, do you agree that the complexity is O(n) seen as O(n) for the nodes + O(n-1) for the edges ??

Comment: didnt get what u wanted to say there ?

Comment: or maybe do i have to consider in any way the cost of the edges ??

Comment: If you implement Gene's solution or my solution below you will get O(N) time complexity including nodes and edges.

Comment: Reason here is that tree is a sparse graph with N-1 edges hence u will get O(N) else in dense graph u need to consider the complexity of edges as well.

Comment: @carlito what Vikram Bhat said is just not true because you have a tree.  As you say there are always n-1 edges for n nodes.  The algorithm is always O(n).  VB must be thinking of a general graph.

Comment: Please move extended discussion to [chat], thanks :)

Comment: @Gene I clearify that i said that because we are working with a tree hence the edge are always N-1 whereas if we were working with some other graph(not tree but some dense graph) then no of edge would be O(N^2) hence we need to consider them

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to do this process in `O(n)`, but whether or not your algorithm actually does depends.

If either "compute the actual leaves" or "remove all the leaves and their edges" loops over the entire tree, that step would take `O(n)`.

And both the above steps will be repeated `O(n)` times in the worst case (if the tree is greatly unbalanced), so, in total, it could take `O(n2)`.

To do this in `O(n)`, you could have each node point to its parent so you can remove the leaf in constant time and maintain a collection of leaves so you always have the leaves, rather than having to calculate them - this would lead to `O(n)` running time.

Answer (score 0):

As your tree is an artitary one. It can also be a link list in which case you would eliminate one node in each iteration and you would need `(n-2)` iterations of `O(n)` to find the leaf.

So your algorithm is actually `O(N^2)`

Here is an better algorithm that does that in `O(N)` for any tree

```
deleteLeaf(Node k) {

 for each child do
     value = deleteLeaf(child)
     if(value>max)
       max = value
     delete(child)
 return max 
}
deleteLeaf(root) or deleteLeaf(root.child)
```